# iOS, Android & Web application development with .Net Web Api architecture & Google http web services

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I'm developing a cross platform application which works with iOS & Android and web application which shares common business logic from .Net Web API. Please see the attached application architecture

[Application architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50U8Y.png)

Mainly our project deals with google maps, so iOS,Android and web app are developed with google iOS SDK, android SDk and javascript SDK  respectively.

For using **Google http web services** like  **Google Maps Directions API**,**Google Maps Distance Matrix API** ,**Google Maps Geocoding API** etc, i'm using **.Net Web API** as common for all the devices so that the business logic will be at one place and easy to maintain, **is this a workable solution? if not what is the correct way to design ?**

Google http web services are free up to 2,500 requests per day.**If i'm consuming google http web services in my web api server then 2500 requests count is for each device or for all devices ?**

Answer (score 0):

The quota limit of the Web service API like [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits) is 2,500 request per day. Meaning every call in this API is count as 1 request. Meaning it is the total request that you can call with this API within the day. For example, Dev A made two request with the API and Dev B also made 2 request with the API. Your total queries per day now is 4. Note that the API has another quota called Requests per 100 seconds. Like the Directions API, it has a limit of 50 request per second. Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks Kendi for your information, hope android and iOS SDk's are billed against device right?